# grails - mapping parameter with chain method

Tags: grails

I want to use the chain method (which is internally calling another action and the issuing a redirect) with the mapping parameter.

How is this possible. I could not find a way to do so.

Comment: Use `chain()` method of controller - http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html

Comment: please read my (very shot) question. I AM using the chain method but a "mapping" parameter is missing that I need

Comment: You can't. Chain is just calling other method passing the model. Then that method can use `redirect` with `mapping` if needed.

Comment: But the action I am calling with the chain method ist just rendering a view and is not redirecting. But I can see that the chain is doing an implicit redirect. The question is: how can I "hook in"

Comment: If you just render the value, why do you need chain?

Comment: ControllerA (chain) --> ControllerB --> render view. This is what chain is all about?!?

Comment: To answer your question: I need the chain method to pass a model which I cannot pass by parameters (what chain is for)